# Convert STRING name of texture to TEXTURE reference in blueprints

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have "Make Brush from Texture" node and I am able to select textures from the dropdown list in editor, but how I can set this texture field realtime from blueprint if its name is saved in the string variable (for example, "af"). Thanks.

Example:

https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/4indn35l/

SUGGESTION:

In theory, there should be an ARRAY with all loaded system textures that I can loop, compare the name of the texture one-by-one, and post the right texture to in-socket of "Make Brush from Texture".

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using soft object paths.

- Create a `Make Soft Object Path` node
- The `Path String` should be the full path of a valid texture. You can see what that should look like by right-clicking one of your textures in the asset browser, selecting 'Copy Reference', and pasting that into a text field.
- Plug the result of the 'Make Soft Object Path' node into a 'Convert to Soft Object Reference` node.
- <s>Plug the result of that into a 'Resolve Soft Reference' node.</s>
- Plug the result of that into a 'Load Asset Blocking' or 'Async Load Asset' node.
- Plug the result of that into a `Cast To Texture2D` node.
- Plug the result of a successful cast into your `Make Brush From Texture` node.

Comment: Sorry, I just found that this approach updates the image only if it was previously selected by hand in the dropdown (cached?). So if I have 100 images in the list, only those that were manually selected at least once in the dropdown are later updated with this approach. Is there any other way?Or is there any way to cache/preload it with some other node runtime?

Comment: so the problem is in the "Cast To Texture2D" node, it executes "Cast Failed" instead of standard exec to next node if the texture was not previously manually selected in the dropdown menu.

Comment: @Kainax See update, the asset must be loaded if it hasn't already been.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted 2 hours to discover that there's a node called "Import File as Texture 2D"[image]

I tried to make @Rotem answer work but every casting fails, it would be useful to me because i'm trying to make the same with .wav files, and unfortunately there's no function for them

Comment: The question (any my answer) deal with loading into memory texture assets that are already imported into the project, not importing assets from image files.

Comment: I know, in fact I upvoted your answer, however I posted the solution that I was looking for just in case anyone needs it..

By the way I ended up converting everything in C++ because blueprint were limiting 